# Rails - send hidden parameter to new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I want to build feedback form to send it body to some e-mail box. Each form belongs to many pages (but page has only one form), has one title and body and can have one e-mail. Now it works like this:

```
app/views/shared/_custom_form.html.slim

= form_for @feedback, method: :post, url: feedback_path, remote: true do |f|
    fieldset.b-form-field style='display:none'
      = f.text_field :email, value: @feedback.email
    fieldset.b-form-field
      = f.label :title, "Title"
      = f.text_field :title, value: @feedback.title
    fieldset.b-form-field
      = f.text_field :body, value: @feedback.body
    fieldset.b-form-field
      = f.submit "Send"

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

  class PagesController < FrontendController
      def show
          @feedback = Feedback.new
      end
  end

app/controllers/feedback_controller.rb
class FeedbackController < FrontendController
  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedback.valid?

        eml_sett =
          if feedback_params[:email]
            feedback_params[:email]
          else
            setting_value(:main_email)
          end
        if eml_sett.present?
          FeedbackMailer.feedback_message(@feedback, eml_sett).deliver
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def feedback_params
    params.require(:feedback).permit(:title, :body, :email)
  end
```

So, @feedback is created in my view, and then it goes from page controller to feedback_controller where it will be sended to form owner or to default email address. It work perfectly (i know, it is better to use hidden_field, but it is raw project), but i want to totally hide e-mail address from html code. So, i tried in my view:

```
= form_for @feedback(email: 'test@test.com')...

= form_for @feedback...
    - @feedback.email = 'test@test.com'

= form_for Feedback.new(email: 'test@test.com')
```

But nothing helped. If I run '- puts @feedback.email' in my view, it returns email value, but in feedback controller 'puts feedback_params[:email]' returns nothing and form is sended to default email box. What am I doing wrong? Where is the mistake? Using Rails 4.1.8/Ruby 2.2.0.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to achieve here, sorry. Do you just want to have the email always default to test@test.com?

Comment: @jon1467, yep, that's right for this current form. Next thing I will replace 'test@test.com' with some variable and will be able to change it from ActiveAdmin. Now I just can't understand - why is this e-mail value cannot be sended to controller this way.

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly then, you can avoid the front end altogether and just (temporarily) set the email address in your create method. Otherwise, you could investigate have a default parameter for that field. A hidden field would also work, but I don't think it's really what you need.

Comment: @jon1467 you mean in feedback_controller, in feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params) ? Is there a way to add a hardcoded email there? And, more interesting, is there a way to declare hardcoded email address in pages_controller and send it to feedback_controller? :)

Comment: You could do that, yeah. When you instantiate `@feedback` in the pages controller, you could just add `@feedback.email = [email]` or add `(email: [email])` to the end of the first line. Then I think you should just be able to _not_ set that value in the form.

Comment: @jon1467 same thing - puts new email value in view, but not send it to feedback controller. :(

Comment: Ah, I think you'll need to do it in the Feedback Controller. Is that what you're wanting to avoid?

Comment: @jon1467 I commented my hidden email field and added (:email: 'test@test.com') to all places in my page and feedback controllers where i can find Feedback.new. And, haha, it did nothing.. I don't understand what is wrong in my code.. It allows email value only from form.

Comment: you 'commented'? You shouldn't need to write it everywhere. Don't suppose you're hosting this project in a public repo somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your `pages#show` action displays a generic page with a 'sign up for newsletter' type of form. However, since you want to capture more data, right now you want to direct the user flow to a feedback page, which is served at `feedback#new`.

If so, what you can do is make the `pages#show` form submit a GET request on `feedback#new`, something like this:

```
= form_for :feedback, url: new_feedback_path, method: :get do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.submit
```

In your `feedback#new` action, you can do something like this:

```
def new
  @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
end
```

If you use `require(:feedback)` in your strong params, then this will be a problem if you want to allow access to the new action without first supplying an email, but I'll leave that for you to decide if you want to support that.

What you are saying about using hidden fields, well you can't avoid it since it is user input. So whether or not you enable it as an editable input field, or keep it hidden, the user can supply any value whatsoever on the first page, which is `pages#show`.

---

If what you need is to hide the email, then yes you don't need a form field anywhere. This is what you do in your controller:

```
def create
  @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)   
  FeedbackMailer.feedback_message(@feedback).deliver
end
```

And in your mailer:

```
class FeedbackMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def feedback_notification(feedback)
    @feedback = feedback
    mail(to: admin_email, from: @feedback.email, subject: @feedback.title)
  end

  private

  def admin_email
    ENV['ADMIN_EMAIL']
  end

end
```

Comment: i completely not interested in user's email. I want to send data from form to site administrators. And each form has its own form.email, and  on submit event all form data will be sended to this email. And I don't want to allow user know administrator's email address, even if he will try to find it in hidden field.

Comment: am I right, there is no solution for such situation?

Comment: Your administrator's email address in the above case is never known since it is hard coded into mailer itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
form_for @feedback... do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :email
```